# How to fetch block's label in xml from phtml in Magento?

Tags: magento

I have a custom block in my layout file like this:

```
<block type="xxx/xxx" name="xxx" template = "bar.phtml">
<label>Foo</label>
</block>
```

How do I get the value of label from bar.phtml ?

Please note I do not want to use setData function to set my variable and pass it.
I want to extract the value inside  tags from the phtml (or anywhere else). I hope its clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a really classy Magento way of doing it since the label of a block purpose is not to be displayed as far as we speak of the frontend.

> **label**: This element is introduced since Magento 1.4. It defines the label of the handle which is shown as a descriptive reference in some areas of the admin panel.

[Source](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/)

I would really warmly recommend you to **stay away from the code below**. But if that is really what you want to achieve, this is a way :

First we get the layout = a big xml concatenation of the layout for that page containing the xml where the block is defined, and thus our label

```
$layout = $this->getLayout();
```

Then we get the current block name in the layout

```
$currentBlockNameInLayout = $this->getNameInLayout();
```

We can, then get the XML node representing the current block in the template. 
`getXpath()` does returns an array, so that is why I used `list()` to get the first item off of this array

```
list($currentBlockInLayout) = $layout->getXpath("//block[@name='".$currentBlockNameInLayout."']");
```

We have what we want and can echo its label element

```
echo $currentBlockInLayout->label;
```

Take care though, this is an object of type `Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element` so if you want to do anything else than displaying it, you would have to use the `__toString()` method

```
var_dump( $currentBlockInLayout->label->__toString() );
```

Full code :

```
$layout = $this->getLayout();
$currentBlockNameInLayout = $this->getNameInLayout();
list($currentBlockInLayout) = $layout->getXpath("//block[@name='".$currentBlockNameInLayout."']");
echo $currentBlockInLayout->label;
var_dump( $currentBlockInLayout->label->__toString() );
```

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting this answer :-)

Comment: This is a great answer, I'm looking for a way to get the parameters of an action called on the block and this answer helped alot after pleanty of googling! I am having a problem getting the action attributes for my specific action, which are added using a reference and a layout update, I'm not seeing the action, but if I solve I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2):

In your XML, use the action method `setData`

```
<block type="xxx/xxx" name="xxx" template = "bar.phtml">
    <action method="setData">
        <label>Foo</label>
    </action>
</block>
```

Then in your `bar.phtml` file, you can retrieve it using `$this->getData('label')`:

```
<?php echo $this->getData('label') ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Axel. I know this already. My question was how to get the vaue in label tag. As you can see in core layout files, most of the blocks have label tag. How do we retrieve its value ?